# Adobe AIR for iPhone app store?

Tags: iphone, air, app-store

Are iPhone apps which are developed with Adobe's AIR allowed on Apple's AppStore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as long as it's well designed, which means you do read the HIG and don't break it. I have one app on AppStore made in this way.

Comment: Complying to the iOS HIG is very, very hard with Adobe Air. Just warning.

Comment: Can you access the iOS address book with AIR?